# How can I get someone's name from a string with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
string = 'company: / name: James / Street: 24 High Road /'
name = re.search('Name:(.*)/(.*)Street:)', string)
print(name)
```

I am trying to get 'James' from the string above with regex, but can't find the solution for this. How can I solve this situation with regex?

Comment: `re.search(r'(?i)name:\s*(\w+)', string).group(1)`

Comment: @anubhava Don't put answers in the comments section.

Comment: Why does your regex look for `Name`, when the string is `name`?

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer as this is the right place for it.

You may use this regex:

```
>>> string = 'company: / name: James / Street: 24 High Road /'
>>> print ( re.search(r'(?i)name:\s*(\w+)', string).group(1) )
James
```

`(?i)` enables ignore case match for your regex.

If you want to assert presence of `Street:` after your match then use this regex with a lookahead assertion:

```
>>> print ( re.search(r'(?i)name:\s*(\w+)(?=\W+Street:)', string).group(1) )
James
```

Answer (score 0):

if the naming convention is consistent you can use a .split() to split it into a list

```
stringy = 'company: / name: James / Street: 24 High Road /'

name = stringy.split('/')
```

edit: This will grab just the element with the name

```
name = [n for n in name if 'name' in n]
```